# How to color a texture in glsl

Tags: colors, textures, glsl, opengl-3, fragment-shader

I need to modify during runtime the appearence of textures..

Some examples may be rendering them with a gray scale to indicate a deactivation, orange color for selection and so on

A little example that better shows what I would like to achieve

[image]

Right now my FS looks pretty simple

```
#version 330

in vec2 fragmentUV;

out vec4 outputColor;

uniform sampler2D textureNode;

void main()
{    
    outputColor = texture(textureNode, fragmentUV).rgba;
}
```

I thought I could control these few cases by setting an uniform variable to some hardcoded values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how you can convert an image into grayscale: http://glsl.heroku.com/e#18369.1

```
float grayScale = dot(imageColor.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114));
if (IsGrayScale){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(grayScale, grayScale, grayScale, 1.0);
} else{
  gl_FragColor = imageColor;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify that shader to make it generic? Or can it work only for gray color?

Comment: @elect can you elaborate? The shader purpose is to convert colored image in to grayscale.

Comment: The code you posted convert a texture into a grayscale. I wish to have a shader where, given a specific color (i.e: instead gray, I would like to have it in an orangescale), convert the texture in the corresponding inputColor-scale.

Comment: Change that to gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(grayScale * targetColor), 1.0); the variable repetition is unnecessary and all GPUs are scalar now.